# Может ли google прокладывать маршрут по воде по заданным пользователем точкам?

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Мне нужно обеспечить возможность прокладывать маршрут по воде. Я раньше никогда не работал с google-maps. Поверхностно просмотрев документацию я так и не понял до конца, можно ли это делать при помощи [google-maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=ru).

Прошу людей сталкивавшихся с данной технологией google, прокомментировать, возможно ли это в целом. Есть ли какие-то кардинальные отличия от работы с маршрутами на суше? Был бы благодарен, за ссылку на пример.

Comment: [How to Use Google Maps for a Boat Route](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-use-google-maps-for-a-boat-route)